# Difference between game server and vps

Tags: counter-strike

I see some game hosting sites which h offer price per slot. And if I want to run 1 cs 1.6 server of 32 slots then price is approximately 15$ , and server runs 24/7 on minimum 4gb ram , good CPU speed and 100 Mbps speed or 1gbps

But if I goto buy vps Of same specs , it. Costs above 30$ in my country. Why???

What is the difference in game server and vps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *Game Server* is only the instance of the server you bought. This means it is limited to only running that particular game with the amount of slots you've paid for. The advantage for the hosting company is that those are easily manageable with no additional license fees.

---

A *VPS* (Virtual Private Server) is an own instance of a whole server system, including an own operating system, where you get full root/admin access.

Server virtualization isn't free. Also they're harder to manage, so extra administration hours are needed to maintain reliability and stability. And you can do whatever you want with it: Install more than one game server, voice server, a webserver,... so the extra stuff you can do with your server may be  paid for as well. Usually VPS come with more disk space than regular game servers and server hard disks are pretty expensive.

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, but I want to know how can they afford to run server on more than 4gb ram, and 100mbps,  and which ISP provides 100mbps unmetered speed in their area for less than 15$. ???

Comment: @Google they can afford it by running multiple game servers per machine. A decent dedicated server can easily have 64 GB of RAM. With a connection of 1 GBit/s you can run 10 game servers on it with dedicated 100 MBit/s and 4 GB of RAM each and still have some RAM spare for the system itself. Let that box cost maybe 60 bucks and sell the servers for 15 each.. 15 * 10 - 60 = 90 bucks profit.